# How would you write this piece of code with lots of if-statements better?

Tags: java, code-readability

```
    if (right == null && parent == null)
        return null;
    else if (right == null)
        return parent;
    else if (parent == null)
        return right;
    else
        return parent.val > right.val ? right : parent;
```

OR

```
    if (right == null && parent == null)
        return null;
    else if (right == null || parent == null)
        return parent == null ? right : parent;
    else
        return parent.val > right.val ? right : parent;
```

Or do you have any other suggestions? I'm looking for a clean code.

Comment: If this is working code that you want to improve, it should be on [codereview.se].

Comment: Any time your code hits a `return`, you don't need an `else`.

Comment: @Turing85 Your suggestion is worse.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because should be in Code Review.

Comment: @PraveenKumar This would likely be closed as example code stub on Code Review.

Comment: I added code-review tag, didn't know it existed!

Comment: Before adding tags, you should read the info. What does the very first sentence of [tag:code-review] yell?

Comment: [codereview.se] is one of our "sister sites" that's 100% dedicated to giving feedback on working code that you're trying to improve. Please be sure to read their help center, though - they're generally really strict about having a [mcve] in particular.

Comment: @EJoshuaS: Actually, [codereview.se] doesn't want a MCVE at all, as that would imply that the code doesn't work as intended.

Comment: @hoffmale True, their MCVE equivalent is different than ours b/c the code has to work. Still has to be minimal, complete, and verifiably working though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to check if both are null. The first if statement below will do that for you (because if `right` and `parent` is null, then null will be returned).

```
if (right == null) {
    return parent;
}

if (parent == null) {
    return right;
}

return parent.val > right.val ? right : parent;
```